# Setting the 'outDir' attribute in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, outdir

I continue to get this error when I attempt to debug a C++ program: `can't launch program 'c:\Users\'my username'\Desktop\C++\'; setting the 'outDir' attribute might help`

I have tried various combinations of syntax so that it would satisfy the condition, but I have had no success. I have spent hours trying to find the proper syntax and I have no idea what my problem is. I have had success with running JavaScript applications but they don't seem to require Source maps or the outDir field to be filled. I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code which is 0.7.10 and I have node downloaded and it seems to work fine. Here is a screenshot so you can get an idea of what I'm seeing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX0TB.png

Comment: I hope you find my answer responsive (if not timely.)   I would like edit your question to eliminate the C++ specific parts.  You OK with that?

Answer (score 1):

The VSCode message `Cannot launch program` ... `setting the 'outDir' attribute might help` can be somewhat misleading, even as recently as VSCode v1.12.2.  I would take it with a grain of salt, it seems to simply mean there was a problem launching the application.

In my case, it was caused by a minor error in my `launch.json` file.   I had:

```
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Gulp",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/{lib,node_modules}/**/*.js",
            "!${workspaceRoot}/lib/tests/**/*.js"
        ]
```

I fixed it by changing one line:

```
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp",
```

Despite the message's attempt to be helpful, the `outFiles` property *may not be necessary or helpful*.   Once I fixed the other problem, debugging *seems* to work fine without it.

Filed as a [vscode issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28257) 6/8/2017

Comment: I do not have the following folder `${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin`. Does the application suppose to run/debug without it or do I need to install grunt. Or grunt get installed automatically when installing `node`? I have an existing application.

Comment: @barnes take a look in the `node_modules/.bin/` folder. Do you have `grunt` there? Are you trying to debug `grunt`? I the answer is yes to both, then set `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/grunt"`. If you don't have `grunt` in `.bin` (the folder for node modules cross platform executables), then set `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt.js"`. I hope you get the pattern. You need to locate the file you want to execute and set that in the `"program"` path.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Only node and mono debugging are supported currently in VSCode. You should set the type in launch.json depending on what you want to debug. More details can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

You get a weird error because you have sourceMaps: true in your launch.json.

Comment: If I set source maps to false, then I get another error saying something along the lines of "Failed to launch, maybe you should try enabling source maps". I can debug no problem with javascript, but I have yet to learn how to do so with other languages. And I have read that web page many times, I still don't what to do exactly.